# what is the best way to parse out CDATA inside XML tags

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, c#-4.0, xml-parsing

i have the following XML that i need to parse in C#:

```
<data>
  <customer_id><![CDATA[1414301]]></customer_id>
  <last_modified_date><![CDATA[2011-08-14 11:58:58]]></last_modified_date>
  <customer_first_name><![CDATA[joe]]></customer_first_name>
  <customer_last_name><![CDATA[blow]]></customer_last_name>
</data>
```

into an object called Result

```
public class Result
{
  public int customer_id;
  public string customer_first_name;
  public string customer_last_name;
}
```

the one thing that i am trying to determine is how to get rid of the

```
 <![CDATA[]]
```

and just parse out the regular values.

What is the best way of converting this XML to the object above that will support the CDATA syntax above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you mean by 'parse'. If you use an XML DOM parser (or any other type), then you have transparent access to the CDATA values.

Answer (score 1):

Using System.XML?  Try [XmlCDataSection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlcdatasection.aspx)?